# Javascript validation display string within webpage rather than alert

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, alert

Hi I currently have a form on submission the following validation rule is checked:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
frmvalidator.addValidation("message","req","Please enter a valid message."); 
</script>

    function Validator(frmname)
{
  this.formobj=document.forms[frmname];
    if(!this.formobj)
    {
      alert("Error: couldnot get Form object "+frmname);
        return;
    }
    if(this.formobj.onsubmit)
    {
     this.formobj.old_onsubmit = this.formobj.onsubmit;
     this.formobj.onsubmit=null;
    }
    else
    {
     this.formobj.old_onsubmit = null;
    }
    this.formobj._sfm_form_name=frmname;
    this.formobj.onsubmit=form_submit_handler;
    this.addValidation = add_validation;
    this.setAddnlValidationFunction=set_addnl_vfunction;
    this.clearAllValidations = clear_all_validations;
    this.disable_validations = false;//new
    document.error_disp_handler = new sfm_ErrorDisplayHandler();
    this.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay=validator_enable_OPED;
    this.EnableOnPageErrorDisplaySingleBox=validator_enable_OPED_SB;
    this.show_errors_together=true;
    this.EnableMsgsTogether=sfm_enable_show_msgs_together;
    document.set_focus_onerror=true;
    this.EnableFocusOnError=sfm_validator_enable_focus;

}
```

However I would like the error message to be displayed on the webpage rather than an alert, could someone please achieve this.

Comment: The problem is not in this line of code, but within the `addValidation()` function itself. You have not shown the inner workings; we cannot help.

Comment: I've modified the code, does this help?

Comment: Nope. That tells us little-to-nothing about what `.addValidation()` does.

Comment: Sorry I have added the correct code now, I'm about of a n00b and followed a tutorial hence the confusion.

Comment: Okay, it's time to keep digging deeper. With some effort on your part you can do this yourself. Look for the code that actually displays the alert. Then figure out how to change it. At a glance, I'd wager it's somewhere inside of `sfm_ErrorDisplayHandler`.

Comment: Ok so I found that commenting out the code in this function doesn't display the alert which is what i wanted however I'm now stuck on how to display the message as a string on my original html file.

Comment: Are you using a third-party validation library? What library. Is there a web page with documentation we can examine, to see if it has options on how to display errors?

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed, at the bottom of the article you can download the full source code: http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/php-email-contact-form.html, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you are using cites the form validator as http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml If you read that, specifically at the top of the second page you will see:

> Showing all the form validation errors together in a message box
>
> If you want to show all the error messages together, then just call
>   the EnableMsgsTogether() function as shown below.
>
> frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();

The text which follows this provides further options for handling of error messages.

You could perhaps try that.